# The performClick () method returns an error

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I have 2 classes that are covered by fragment.
home.java 
hometwo.java

Clicking the button named btn of my class named home.java.
I want my class named hometwo.java to be clicked automatically on the button named btnctwo.

home.java

```
public class home extends Fragment {
    Button btn;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);



        btn =  rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnc);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        hometwo hometwox = new hometwo();

        hometwox.btnctwo
                .post(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        hometwox.btnctwo.performClick();

                    }
                });
    }
});

        return rootView;



    }
}
```

hometwo.java

```
public class hometwo extends Fragment {
    Button btnctwo;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);



        btnctwo =  rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnctwo);






btnctwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.e("testler","testlertwo");

    }
});

        return rootView;



    }



}
```

logcat

```
2020-05-18 11:17:54.907 11290-11290/com.sahnartsappone.sahnartsapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sahnartsappone.sahnartsapp, PID: 11290
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.Button.post(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object reference
        at com.sahnartsappone.sahnartsapp.home$1.onClick(home.java:30)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Why does the performClick () method not work?
Where am I making mistakes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
hometwo hometwox = new hometwo();

        hometwox.btnctwo
                .post...
```

If you only create the fragment it will not reach the `onCreateView` method and therefore it won't inject the `btnctwo` button from `hometwox` with the button instance from the view (as there won't be any view). So basically you will call the `post` method on a null reference.

So the solution would be to render the fragment using something like this:

```
 FragmentTransaction transaction = this.fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
```

Comment: hello thank you for your reply.
but I couldn't fully understand.
How can I apply the code sample you provided.
I made the following code sample but it didn't work.         https://pasteboard.co/J8VtSl1.png